# Using Display modes(for mobile) with ASP.NET MVC 5 ( Core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-1.0, displaymode

Good evening.
I am working on Asp.net Mvc 5 ( Now its called  "core" )
And i have one problem.

its about Display modes.

With Asp.net Mvc 4 ,its so easy.
Just change File name like
 **index.Mobile.cshtml**
Then we can handle it.

But with Mvc 5, its not easy.
I already tried change name

**index.Mobile.cshtml**

but its not working.
I searched a lot , but i couldn't find any correct answer about it.
Please Help me...

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: It is called mvc for asp.net core now i believe.